# Express push method not updating the JSON data file

Tags: node.js, express

I am a beginner to Express/node platform and working on sample code. Once the npm server is started, the initial data string is read from employeeData.js file - which is a JSON string.The sample code with me is able to add/edit/create new records (employee) and I print it. But, the changes are not being written to the actual data file. Can any one help on this ?

From the data insertion code:

```
saveemployee: function(employee, callback) {
        currentID = currentID + 1;
    employee.id = currentID;
    employees.push(employee);
        callback(null, _clone(employee));
    }
```

Actual JSON data in data directory(data/employeeData.js)

```
module.exports = {
  employees:
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "test1",
      "post": "post1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "test2",
      "post": "post2"
    }
};
```

Comment: For now, your data is updated only in RAM. Are you trying to persist it to `.js`-source file ?! maybe create `json` instead

Comment: It is reading from:data/employeeData.js file, but not writing in to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, your data is updated only in RAM, you can persist your changes to, for example, `json`-file, but not `js`-source-file (actually you can do both, but the second case looks really weird).

> For `json` file-db you can use [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb)

Code sample:

```
const low = require('lowdb');
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync');

const adapter = new FileSync('employees.json');
const db = low(adapter)

db.defaults({ employees:  [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "test1",
      post: "post1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "test2",
      post: "post2"
    },
  ]})
  .write()

// Add an employee
db.get('employees')
  .push({
    id: 3,
    name: "test1",
    post: "post1"
  })
  .write();
```